# If I plug the ground with neutral on top of the power switch,

Tags: ground

If I plug the ground with neutral on top of the power switch, it will affect output when I plug this into the pump hole, where the local loop is "zeroed." The Earth is taken through the coil T5 which is presumably connected to the "trippy" in the switch.

[image]

Comment: Do the instructions say to do that?  Your location matters if you can do that.  I imagine you are in Europe from the wire colours and voltage.  Looks like a ground symbol on the left hand side.

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask] and take the [tour] for tips.

Comment: What kind of piece of equipment are we looking at? What does "plug the ground with neutral" mean - are you connecting both ground & neutral to the same screw? What "pump hole"? What is a "local loop" and how is it "zeroed"? What is 'the "trippy" in the switch'? These are likely well known terms where you live, but don't necessarily translate directly to American English...

Comment: Please [edit] your post to describe your situation more clearly.  Never, never, never attach safety ground to any conductor, unless you are in a rare situation where that is required by local electrical codes or the instructions on the APPROVED (not cheap chinese) equipment.  For instance in North America, the first disconnect switch past the electric meter bonds neutral to ground, by Code and design. In Europe they do something else entirely.